# How do I filter my array to display only specific category items?

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, nspredicate

This code currently lists all my categories. However I will like to filter this result to display specific results. For example... The array contains the items Jamaica, Japan, Germany and Asia. I will like to filter the displayed results to only show Japan and Germany. I've read NSPredicate can assist me but i'm not too sure on how to implement it here.

Datacontroller.M

```
+(NSArray*) getCategories {

AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext* context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"StoreCategory" inManagedObjectContext:context];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

return fetchedObjects;
}
```

---

Categories.m

```
   -(UITableViewCell*)MGListView:(MGListView *)listView1 didCreateCell:(MGListCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(cell != nil) {

    StoreCategory* cat = [listViewMain.arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell.labelTitle setText:cat.category];
    [self setImage:cat.category_icon imageView:cell.imgViewThumb];


}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter the unwanted category in this method because `indexPath` will be a sequence of indices.

You will have to build another array that includes the category you want before `UITableView` delegate or DataSource functions are called, for example, in `ViewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

This method seemed to do the trick.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR category CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Japan", @"Germany", context];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```